# Rsync over ssh over proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, rsync

My computer currently has access to the internet only through a proxy, thus I'm forwarding my ssh connection to port 8080 through corkscrew.

I need to run rsync over this ssh connection - does anyone know how to make it work? Just typing "rsync username@destination-ssh-server:folder-name" doesn't work since this doesn't forward the ssh traffic to port 8080.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this using the command

```
rsync -v -e ssh Host:remote-folder destination-folder
```

where `Host` was a host configuration in my `.ssh/config` file that used corkscrew using the `ProxyCommand` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port using "-p 8080".

Comment: The -p option I believe is for setting destination permissions to be the same as source permissions. At any rate when I execute rsync -p 8080 source destination, it thinks 8080 is a file and fails.

Answer (score 0):

First you declare in your exports the proxy connection information

> export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxyhost:8080

Then you declare that you want `rsync` to use this proxy for its traffic

> RSYNC_PROXY=user:password@proxyhost:8080

You modify the above based on your proxy connection requirements (some do not need user/password)

Finally you run your rsync job.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -J username1@111.111.11.11:60010 username2@222.222.22.22' source/ destination/
```